# Dynamically TextBlock in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textblock

I have project in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, Including reference "Dynamic data Display" Map chartplotter.
I have a line between two points and I want to set the length of the line in the middle of the line( Or beside one of the points it doesn't matter). As I understand there is no any way to enter a label on wpf control so I decide to try the TextBlock. So I need to do it for every line I am creating in the running time, so it should be dynamic. 
That's what I did :

```
TextBlock textBlockTemp = new TextBlock(); // Creating the textblock
textBlockTemp.Text = lengthLine.ToString(); // Set the text to be the length of the line
```

**Now what to do next to set the position of the textBlock ?**
I have the 2 points and the length line. 
Thank's in advice.

EDIT :
The resualt I want is :

```
             35
0----------------------------0
```

I have the line and the points in the sides. Just need to add the length text.

Comment: Can you show a visual example?

Comment: Yes, I edit. @Shaaryar

Answer (score 0):

I know normally link isn't an answer, but maybe this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22952/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part will help you. At the bottom there is section about adorners, but you have to look in the code. I hope you find what you're looking for.